# google datastore api explorer example

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to understand

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1beta1/datastore.datasets.blindWrite

but I always get

```
503 Service Unavailable

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Can you provide a example as simple as possible I can paste to verify it actually works?
I tried something like this.

```
{
 "mutation": {
  "insertAutoId": [
   {
    "key": {
     "path": [
      {
       "kind": "person",
       "name": "gert"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you followed one of the first two activation flows described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate). And created the project *recently*, an App Engine application should be already associated with your project.

You need to:

- Click `Authorize your request using OAuth 2.0`
- Leave `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope checked
- Add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore` under `Add additional scopes (optional)`
- Click `Authorize` and grant the permission
- Specify the `datasetId` parameter (same as your `project-id`)
- Use `insert` or `upsert` instead of `insertAutoId` if the key is complete (kind w/ name or id).

Example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta1/datasets/my-dataset-id/blindWrite...

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ...
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "mutation": {
  "insert": [
   {
    "key": {
     "path": [
      {
       "kind": "Foo",
       "name": "iamfoo"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}

200 OK

{
 "kind": "datastore#blindWriteResponse",
 "mutationResult": {
  "indexUpdates": 1
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still give me 503? Also if I deliberately log out i get 401 Unauthorized so i don't think it is authorization? Maybe it is the datasetid which i use from the projectid from the api console? Putting something random in it also give me 503.

Comment: If I go to https://cloud.google.com/console and click on my project I dont see cloud datastore only cloud storage? Adding cloud datastore in the https://code.google.com/apis/console as active service does not add it in https://cloud.google.com/console?

Comment: You need to enable a app engine application, after creating a new project and app engine application it works.

Comment: Yes, the first two activation flows described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) assume that you have a *new* [cloud.google.com](cloud.google.com) project that automaticaly create the App Engine application for you. Edit my answer.

Comment: please answer my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062332/what-is-the-datasetid-for-google-cloud-datastore-json-api