# What is the datasetId for Google Cloud Datastore JSON API

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097451/how-do-i-find-my-datasetid-for-making-google-datastore-queries#answer-25108007) post, the `datasetId` is the name of the cloud project.

It is working fine, if my project has a name like "`project-name`".
In my case, the project name is "`domainName.com:project-name`". In this case what is `datasetId`.

I tried with domain and removing the domain name, no luck.

Comment: Can you send me an email (eddavisson@google.com) with your project ID?

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Datastore API is not currently supported for projects whose name begins with a domain/colon (e.g. "example.com:project"), but we plan to support this in the next version of the API.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/82